# Is there a module or easy way to break up nodes into multiple pages?

Tags: paging

Is there a module or easy way to break up nodes (ie blog posts) into multiple pages?

Comment: Easiest way to do it normally is the opposite: Create multiple nodes and join them together on a different page.

Answer (score 5):

The [paging module](http://drupal.org/project/paging) will help you with that

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the [paging module](http://drupal.org/project/paging) or possibly other contributed modules but you did use blog posts as an example so just to be clear - you could use the core teaser system - which works like a wordpress read more and allows you to show the "teaser" on lists verses the full node when viewing it.

Here is a pretty informative article on how to use it, config etc.

[Manually controlling the teaser break point](http://drupal.org/node/176829)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) to generate node list with pager.